# Input type image doesn't submit the form when you hit enter

Tags: html, forms

I have a form and the input you need to click to submit the form has type="image". I want to make it so when your focusing on another input of the form  and you hit enter the form is submitted (as if you clicked the input type image).

Do I need to use javascript to create this behavior?

Is this default behavior and considered good accessibility, usability and UX? Im pretty sure ive seen it on a number of sites.

Comment: Well a submit button should be type="submit", so change that if you can. If not, you need to add a keypress listener to the text inputs, when the input = enter, trigger the submit "image"

Comment: So this keypress listener would be javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form needs an `action` attribute, referring to the script which will process the results - for example:

```
<form id="myform" action="./myform.php">
    <!-- the rest of your form -->
</form>
```

Without an `action` attribute, the form cannot be submitted as the browser doesn't know where to submit it to.

Answer (score 0):

have you used `<form> </form>` tags
try this> UPDATED CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform_myfn()
    {
      alert("form getting submitted");
      document.forms["myform"].submit();
      if(document.getElementById('a').value!="")
        {
            alert("input box value "+document.getElementById('a').value);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please enter some value in input box and submit again");
        }
    }



    </script>



<form name="myform">
Put some value for input box and try submitting form by clicking image
<input type="text" id="a" name="a" />

<input type="image"   style=" background:url(http://www.youthcancertrust.org/cms/site/images/RTEmagicC_play_button.png.png) no-repeat; display:block; width:300px; height:306px; "  onclick="submitform_myfn()" />


</form>
```

Comment: The type needs to be image not submit.

Comment: I have changed type from submit button to image and have updated the code above. give a try

Comment: His problem isn't that clicking the `input type=image` doesn't submit the form, it's that _pressing enter_ doesn't submit the form.

Comment: well, jdln says "I want to make it so when your focusing on another input of the form and you hit enter the form is submitted (as if you clicked the input type image). ". if you have  input elements inside <form></form>tags and if u keep cursor on any input box, and hit enter it will get submitted. so I feel this is what he expecting..!!? Please try above code